# Should a comma be used when ending with in my opinion?

Tags: commas

Which sentence is correct?

1- She was a great singer, in my opinion at least.
2- She was a great singer in my opinion at least.

1- sounds correct, but I'm not sure if it is because the phrase "in my opinion at least" is essential to the meaning of the sentence (i.e. it may not be everyone that thinks she's a great singer).

If 1- is correct, which comma rules are we applying here? I was mainly focusing on using commas to separate non-restrictive elements, but as a I explained above, I'm not sure this a non-restrictive element as it changes the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I'd agree that [1] sounds correct, or rather better reflects how most people would usually say it (with a pause). But there would be situations where I'd choose [2] instead: "_Ali_ says she was rubbish, _Babs_ says she was mediocre, _Colin_ says he disliked her songs, and _Debbie_ wouldn't listen to her." ...  "[Well,] s/She was a great singer in _my_ opinion at least." (I might add a comma after 'opinion' here.) Where clarity of meaning isn't compromised, comma usage can be fairly free, and used merely to show pauses the writer chooses in speech.

Comment: I think it scans better if you write ", at least in my opinion".

Comment: A comma is preferable. "In my opinion at least" is a supplementary adjunct, one that is not integrated into the structure of the clause, and thus best set apart by punctuation such as a comma.

Comment: You could say it either way with fractionally different meanings: with a comma, it suggests that you are qualifying your earlier statement, without you are directly expressing an opinion. Without a comma it's like "My opinion is: ...", with a comma it's more like "She's a great singer, well maybe, you might disagree, but that's what I think at least."

Answer (score 0):

Your first is correct because there are two, separate statements there.

One is she was a great singer; the other is that that's your opinion.

True or not, 'She was a great singer in my opinion at least' with no punctuation can never have a clear meaning in English grammar; only in general context.